# mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'binary-mode=1'

Tags: mysql

when I am using this command to dump my MySQL 5.7 database:

```
mysqldump -h10.10.1.3 -uroot -p123456 -P3306 --single-transaction --master-data=2 mysql>test.sql
```

shows error:

```
mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'binary-mode=1'
```

why would this happen and what should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: The `binary-mode` flag is generally only used when restoring a MySQL database that contains blob data. If you're seeing it when trying to export, someone may have added it somewhere in a `my.cnf` file. You'll want to check those to make sure the variables and settings are correct for the version of MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

On my hand, I think you should unzip the file first before import , check the file format and perform an unzip if you have a zip file.